# ¿Alguien podría decirme que fallo he cometido en este programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Verán, mi intención sería que mi programa escribiera todas las posibles combinaciones de caracteres en txt.txt, pero no escribe nada y continúa ejecutándose.

```
import random
from random import choice
a='''QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLÑZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghklñzxcvbnm1234567890@#€¡¿!?.:;'=Ç}{+-_ÁÍÓÚÉÜáíóúéü)(/&%$ºª\<>,"'''
b=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
c=10
while (c==10):
    d = random.choice(b)
    e = ""
    f = e.join([choice(a) for i in range(d)])
    x = open("txt.txt", 'r')
    w = [line.split(',') for line in x.readlines()]
    if f in w == False:
        y=open("txt.txt", "a")
        y.write(f + '\n')
r = open('txt.txt', 'r')
print(r.read())
```

Comment: `c=10 while (c==10)` ¿qué propósito tiene esta línea?

Comment: Hola Dani, no queda muy claro lo que quieres decir con "todas las posibles combinaciones de caracteres". ¿Todas las combinaciones posibles usando de uno a 30 caracteres con repetición? Si es esto, random es una mala idea, y coincido con Mauricio en su duda.Si pudieras explicar mejor lo que buscas conseguir sería posible orientarte mejor porque además de los errores el algoritmo en si es muy ineficiente a no ser que pretendas conseguir algo distinto a lo que creo.

Comment: En cuanto a problemas en tu código, no modificas la variable de control `c` dentro del ciclo por lo que `c==10` siempre va a ser cierta y como consecuencia tienes un ciclo infinito, abres el archivo repetidamente y nunca lo cierras como ya te han comentado y la sintaxis `if f in w == False:` es incorrecta, ese `if` siempre es falso, debe ser `if f not in w:`

Answer (score 2):

El valor de la variable `c` nunca es modificado, por lo que entra en bucle infinito.

Aparte el archivo no lo cierras, por lo que tampoco hace nada.

Ejemplo:

```
r.close
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable C nunca cambia de valor lo que hace imposible que salga del ciclo while por lo tanto nunca deja de ejecutarse.